# How to import specific columns from a Google spreadsheet using Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet (Book Form) that is populated by a form which is open to the public, but the results are private. I need to make a separate spreadsheet (Available Books) that will only display certain columns from the original spreadsheet. That way, I can make the new spreadsheet public that only displays the available books from the Book Form spreadsheet.

I would need to do this in Google Scrips, which I am very new at and haven't had hardly any experience. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a great application for Google-Apps-Script, you'll be able to do it. However, your question is far to broad for this forum. I suggest you start with the script tutorials to start, then look at examples of Form Submission trigger functions. If you have specific pieces that you're stuck on, come back and ask.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 'importrange' function within google spreadsheets (https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtksdC_OJH9LdDh0eHpaamVBMU1sYUdhMHEwRWw2LXc#gid=0

This is an example of a public sheet pulling in private data.